# Thesis Defense Bare Pass, Issues with Supervisor

Tags: thesis, thesis-committee

For my Masters degree (MSc), I completed a thesis with my supervisor. I edited and cleaned the thesis to the point where my supervisor only had minor comments and polished it to the best of my ability.

During the defense, my supervisor and another grader (let's call him John) were marking. My research was qualitative in nature. John said that my research objectives and questions were invalid because they were quantitative in nature, not qualitative. John said that this was a glaring issue.

I was deeply shocked, because I had revised the research questions / objectives multiple times with my supervisor who knew that my research was qualitative. I finalised the research question, and showed to my supervisor how my research meets the objectives / questions. He gave his thumbs up. My supervisor never flagged this as a problem.

After some deliberation, both John and my supervisor said that they were uncertain if I would pass / fail and would need a few weeks to grade my thesis as-is. It was not possible to edit or change the thesis.

Two weeks passed, and I felt depressed. I feared failing the degree and losing several years of my life. My supervisor came back to me to tell me that they had passed me, but only gave a bare passing grade.

I feel deflated. On one hand, I am happy I passed, and I will get my degree. The grade itself isn't reflected on the certificate.

On the other, I dont understand why despite my best efforts I can only get mediocre grades. My supervisor even said I put in significant effort in the project, and I was hoping to get at least an A.

I believe my supervisor himself did not know about the problems with my research question, which is why if it was such a glaring issue, it should have been flagged immediately.

What would you advise me to do? It seems unfair that this happened.
Should I appeal the grade that I got? Would it be possible, on the grounds that such a glaring issue was not flagged out?

Comment: This is unanswerable, as you haven't said anything here about what you actually want from the situation at this point in time. Do you want to make a complaint about your supervisor? Make sure he never supervises again? Make a complaint about John? Appeal the grade? Simply move on? It seems the situation pretty much resolved itself, it's unclear what further course of action is needed.

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: Well, it will not look good for your supervisor going forward, likely, but that does you no good. But, this is one reason there are external graders in many places. How was the grader chosen?

Comment: Did you have a discussion with your supervisor about this? Did you tell him that from his reactions to your work you believed you had no reason to worry? Did you ask him for how he explains  the discrepancy between his apparent positive feedback to you and the result you finally got?

Comment: "The grade itself isn't reflected on the certificate." - Does the grade matter at all, then, for practical purposes besides your own feelings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, please allow me to congratulate you on your defending your thesis, in the face of very tough circumstances. Your defence (or defense, if you are in the US) was an uphill battle -- which you eventually won. Not by knockout, but by points -- but you did win it.

Now, your questions.

- "What would you advise me to do?"

IMHO, there is nothing you should now be doing about this.  Moreover, your may consider giving yourself a command to stop even thinking about this.  You have passed, and this entire situation is no longer worth a joule of your energy or a second of your time.  Wipe this episode from your memory, forget about this grade, and go on with your life.

- "It seems unfair that this happened."

It seems unfair -- and it really is.  Sorry if my tone sounds too didactic and even cynical, but you have already reached the age at which you must know that life is *profoundly unfair*.  It is a big oversight to expect fairness of it. Get prepared to meet more characters like this John.

- "Should I appeal the grade that I got?"

Whatever decision you make, my recommendation would be to put your health, including your psychological health, first.  Always put it above your grades, awards, etc.  Also, value your time.  How much of your health and time will be spent for this appeal -- and how much will you gain from it, even if you succeed?  Will an increase of your grade influence your future career in any way?
Pick your battles.

Comment: Thank you. Marked as the answer.

Comment: This is such a good piece of advice. Especially the last sentence!

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for your experience and I hope you will be able,  with time, to live peacefully with it. I agree that your best course is to move on without putting a lot more mental energy into it.

I do feel a need to comment on the fairness of this situation. You are correct - this situation is unfair. From your account it certainly seems that you are being penalized for a lack of competent advice. But I would strongly caution you to reject any counsel that "life is unfair." I used to find that to be an appealing statement. As I matured, I discovered that I was much happier when I abandoned that point of view. A "fair game" has even odds so you win and lose at about the same rate. I have found that, taken on a day by day basis, life has provided many more wins than losses. I acknowledge that this may not be true for absolutely everyone, but I don't think that it is a common experience.

I'm now in my fourth score of years and have found that meeting each experience on its own has been very helpful. There have certainly been many unfair experiences along the way, but the vast majority have been fair. So, I believe that *life is fair* and meeting it with that attitude leads to both serenity and success.

Best wishes as you start the next phase of your career.